# Pyspark gives different df.count() result on every other run

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am using AWS EMR (v 6.11.1), PySpark (v 3.3.2). After some transformations (mainly after groupBy, dropDuplicates) on data getting different values in output of pyspark.sql.DataFrame.count() on every other run.

Consider the below example:

```
df = spark.read.parquet(file_path)
logger.info(f'initial count {df.count()}') 
'''output: 27,600,000 (same count on every run)'''

'''function derives new columns using multiple aggregation functions like max,min, sum'''
df2 = some_aggregations(on_group_keys=['col1','col2']) 
logger.info(f'count after aggregation {df2.count()}') 
'''output : 19,300,000/19,300,005/19,300,003 (diff count on every run)'''

df2 = df2.dropDuplicates(['col3','col4','col5','col6','col7']) 
logger.info(f'count after drop duplicate {df2.count()}') 
'''output : 19,200,010/19,200,050/19,200,035 (diff count on every run)'''
```

Here, I am able to get consistent count values on 1st log.
But on the 2nd and 3rd log, it returns different values on different executions.

*How to resolve this issue please suggest.*
*Can data shuffling or incorrect spark application/cluster configurations cause this issue?*

**Note** -

- This issue is not reproducible on a small dataset.
- mentioned df count output values are approximate.
- The input data size is ~90 GB & final output data size is ~50 GB.
- Using Configuration

  - total executers 114
  - cores per executor 5
  - executor/driver memory 37 G
  - spark default parallelism 1700
  - spark memory fraction 0.80
  - spark memory storage fraction 0.30
  - spark max driver result size 20 G

Already tried solutions like df.persist() to achieve consistency in the count
but it didn't return constant count values across different runs.

I am expecting a consistent count at 2nd, 3rd log on every run when the input data is the same.

Comment: Are there any udfs involved in `some_aggregations` that are not deterministic? Or any other transformations that includes random variables?

Comment: Is it possible that _something_ is writing to that directory between executions? I see this sometimes when people set their logging directory to be the same as the data directory. Can you take a look at the location (presumably in S3?) to see if new files are being added?

Comment: @werner no udfs involved in some_aggregations(). Can you please elaborate ?- "any other transformations that include random variables" I believe in this case only dropDuplicates will give random output.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, the log and output files are stored in different s3 directories. And gp2 EBS volumes are used for execution/storage purposes.

Comment: Can you add a code that reproduce the bug here ? Try 4–5 random lines of input and see if they reproduce the bug, if not, the responses here will only be guesses.

Comment: +1 for a some sort indeterminism in the `some_aggregations`. Some SQL-functions are explicitly marked as non-deterministic in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html). Furthermore, a source of non-determinism can be more subtle: for example, `sum(unordered_float_column)` is not deterministic.

Comment: So, we would need to see what `some_aggregations` does and what sort of data is in the columns.